# Simulating a fair coin with 2 special fair coins

Tags: probability

Assume we have 2 fair coins that I will name them "select" and "apply". I toss the "select" coin once and I keep the outcome in my mind. Then I will toss the "apply" coin and if it is Heads I will write down the outcome of the "select" coin. If the "apply" coin is Tails, I will flip the "select" coin for a new turn.

In the case that the "apply" coin is Heads, I will continue tossing the "apply" coin until I get Tails. Every time the "apply" coin is Heads I will write down the outcome of the "select" coin. When I get Tails I will return back to the "select" coin for a new turn.

Example:

1. Toss "select" -> Tails (keep in mind)
2. Toss "apply" -> Heads (I write down Tails)
3. Toss "apply" -> Heads (I write down Tails)
4. Toss "apply" -> Tails (I stop tossing "apply" and return to "select")

Is this simulating a standard fair coin? How can I prove it (yes/no).

If no, is there a way to alter the "apply" coin to make the system behave like a fair coin?

Comment: This is very tangential, and may be deleted soon, but (assuming that like me you are not a native speaker), you may want to avoid using expressions such as "gives me Heads" whenever possible.

Comment: @ClementC. Ahahah That's funny ^^

Comment: @ClementC. thanks :P

Comment: Why are you attempting to simulate a fair coin with two fair coins? Just flip one of the coins! Certainly, it is a math question, but would be more interesting to ask if 2 unfair coins can be used to simulate a fair coin.

Comment: @TonyK interesting that you say that! But if you have a biased "apply" coin, then the number of consecutive (let's say) Tails might be much longer than a fair coin right?

Comment: Anyways, as long as you have a fair coin, might as well use it. If you have a coin and do not know whether it is faire, von Neumann's trick is here for you -- no need for a second.

Comment: In this case what outcome are you accepting?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif If I stop the tosses at step 4 then the "output" is TT.

Comment: So the outcome of select is determined once you get Tails on 'apply' is it?

Comment: What I had in mind is that the outcome is determined every time 'apply' is Heads actually.

Answer (score 0):

After the procedure has given a result, there are two ways to get the same result again: either "apply" results in "Heads", or you restart the procedure and it then happens to give the same result again. The probability is therefore $1/2+1/2\cdot1/2=3/4$, whereas with a normal coin the probability is $1/2$.

You get a better approximation to a normal coin if the probability for "Heads" of "apply" is reduced, but as long as that probability is above zero, the probability for repeated results will be greater than $1/2$, and if it is zero, you get no results.